# Loop through select query results from a table and Update column in same table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, cursor

Table A has the data like this

```
JID  P_ID P_CODE   COMM      MDATE
---  ---- ------   ----      ---------
1     112  WXCVA   null      2-feb-19  
1     112  UCXVA   WXCVA     09-sep-19 
2     222  DCVA    null      08-aug-18   
2     222  UCVA    DCVA      09-dec-09
```

There are 200 records like this. Now I need to read those records and update the mdate for secondary codes. The result table need to look like this

```
JID  P_ID P_CODE   COMM      MDATE
---  ---- ------   ----      ---------
1     112  WXCVA   null      2-feb-19  
1     112  UCXVA   WXCVA     2-feb-19 
2     222  DCVA    null      08-aug-18   
2     222  UCVA    DCVA      08-aug-18
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: Edit you r question and show the results you want to create.

Comment: from the above-given table kindly provide the result table as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table mytab(p_id number, p_code varchar2(10), comm varchar2(10), mdate date);

insert into mytab values(112, 'WXCVA', null, to_date('20190202','yyyymmdd'));
insert into mytab values(112, 'UCXVA', 'WXCVA', to_date('20190909','yyyymmdd'));
insert into mytab values(222, 'DCVA', null, to_date('20180808','yyyymmdd'));
insert into mytab values(222, 'UCVA', 'DCVA', to_date('20091209','yyyymmdd'));

COMMIT;

select * from mytab;

P_ID P_CODE COMM  MDATE
112  WXCVA  NULL  02-FEB-19
112  UCXVA  WXCVA 09-SEP-19
222  DCVA   NULL  08-AUG-18
222  UCVA   DCVA  09-DEC-09
```

Merge statement to perform the required update.

```
MERGE INTO MYTAB C
USING (SELECT A.P_ID, B.P_CODE, B.COMM, A.MDATE 
         FROM MYTAB A 
              INNER JOIN 
              MYTAB B 
           ON A.P_ID = B.P_ID 
          AND A.P_CODE = B.COMM) D
   ON (   C.P_ID = D.P_ID 
      AND C.P_CODE = D.P_CODE)
 WHEN MATCHED 
 THEN UPDATE SET C.MDATE = D.MDATE;

select * from mytab;

P_ID P_CODE COMM  MDATE
112  WXCVA  NULL  02-FEB-19
112  UCXVA  WXCVA 02-FEB-19
222  DCVA   NULL  08-AUG-18
222  UCVA   DCVA  08-AUG-18
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
update tab
   set mdate = (select t2.mdate
                from tab t2
                where t2.p_code = tab.comm
               )
   where tab.comm is not null;
```

Comment: u beat me to the answer just as I was typing this :(

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for answering this. That select query which you posted is same as the query I posted., giving the list of mdates. And so direct update query is not working. Receiving error "right paranthesis missing" . So I was thinking maybe I need a cursor or a temp table to put the result set of select statement. and then do update for each record in that. I am not a oracle person. so checking for that sample code of cursor..

Comment: @GSR . . . I don't understand your comment.  This is an `update` query, which makes it quite different from your query.  It also doesn't have a `from` clause in the outer query.  You should not need a cursor to do what you want.

Comment: @Gordon got you. Thanks a lot, I need it the other way around, meaning update the date where the p_code=comments, so am trying to modify the query you provided,                                                                                    
    update tab t2
   set t2.mdate = (select t1.mdate
                from tab t1
                where t1.p_ID = t2.p_id and (t1.comments IS NULL OR t1.comments ='0') )
   where t2.comments=t1.p_code and t2.p_ID=t1.p_ID; this is throwing invalid identifier t1.p_ID. any suggestion ?

Comment: @GSR . . . You cannot reference `t1` in the outer `where` clause.  I don't fully understand what you want to accomplish with that.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Hi Gordon,                       as per the exampe data, here I want to get the mdate of the row that has p_code=WXCVA and p_id =112 and update the mdate of the row where comm = WXCVA   . This is what I need. .                                                                                     
    JID  P_ID P_CODE   COMM      MDATE
    ---  ---- ------   ----      ---------
    1     112  WXCVA   null      2-feb-19  
    1     112  UCXVA   WXCVA     09-sep-19 
    2     222  DCVA    null      08-aug-18   
    2     222  UCVA    DCVA      09-dec-09

Comment: @DanielEuchar edited the question and added expected result  set

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited the question and added expected result  set

Answer (score 0):

For the sample data that you posted this update statement should work:

```
update tablename t
set t.mdate = (
  select mdate
  from tablename
  where p_id = t.p_id and comm is null
)
where t.comm is not null;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=786bb385312d05d38af927853ccd7d85).
Results:

```
P_ID | P_CODE | COMM  | MDATE    
---: | :----- | :---- | :--------
 112 | WXCVA  | null  | 02-FEB-19
 112 | UCXVA  | WXCVA | 02-FEB-19
 222 | DCVA   | null  | 08-AUG-18
 222 | UCVA   | DCVA  | 08-AUG-18
```